# Simple pivoting of DataFrame in python should work. Is this a bug when passing 'values' argument? If so, how to fix it?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

Unless I'm missing something very obvious. Some mock data:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'epoch':['a','b','c','a','b','c'],'duration':[1,2,3,4,5,6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.pivot(df.index,'epoch')
```

In this case, I get a nice pivoted data frame with a multi index. However, as said in the documentation, by passing the third argument 'values', I should get one with one level index.

However, if instead of the last line, I use

```
df.pivot(df.index,'epoch','duration')
```

I get an error 'IndexError: indices are out-of-bounds'.

Why is this? Is there a simple way to get the output I want (a data frame without multi index) without changing python version?
I'm using python 2.7 with an ipython notebook in case it matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the module-level `pivot_table` function:

```
>>> pd.pivot_table(df, index=df.index, columns='epoch', values='duration')
epoch   a   b   c
0       1 NaN NaN
1     NaN   2 NaN
2     NaN NaN   3
3       4 NaN NaN
4     NaN   5 NaN
5     NaN NaN   6
```

I confess I do not understand why `pd.pivot`, `pd.pivot_table` and `DataFrame.pivot` all exist, with slightly different behavior.  It is one of the places where the pandas API shows a lack of consistency.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if this is something that has been fixed in other versions, or if there are at least plans to make it more consistent?

Comment: @Alejandro: I don't know of any plans in this regard.  The pandas API is still evolving and there are a fair number of cases like this where there are multiple ways of doing things and it's not clear which one is the most recent and/or most thought-out one.